# Creating Page Object instances in Specflow

Tags: c#, selenium, bdd, specflow

I've been struggling with my problem for some time, and I decided to ask for help. So I'm writing my GitHub repository so I can put it in my CV. The problem is I decided to use BDD along with my Selenium and I can't figure out how to stop repeating myself during Step Definitions. As I create my code in Page Object Oriented model I keep repeating myself creating instances of an object in every step. I Discovered that I can use something like ScenarioContext.Current, but to be honest, I must've been using it wrong, since it doesen't look as good as I would like to. I hope for some advices on how to make my code better. Here's a Sample:

```
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace SampleAutomationTests.StepDefinitions
{
    [Binding]
    public sealed class AuthenticationFeatureSteps
    {
        [Given(@"I opened the home page")]
        public void GivenIOpenedTheHomePage()
        {
            HomePage page = new HomePage(Hooks.Driver);
            ScenarioContext.Current["Home Page"] = page;
            page.GoTo();
        }

        [Given(@"I navigated to Basic Auth link")]
        public void GivenINavigatedToBasicAuthLink()
        {
            HomePage page = (HomePage)ScenarioContext.Current["Home Page"];
            AuthenticationPage authenticationPage = page.GoToAuthenticationPage();
            ScenarioContext.Current["authenticationPage"] = authenticationPage;

        }
}
}
```

Comment: We have a bigger example how to use SpecFlow and Selenium here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow-Examples/tree/master/ASP.NET-MVC/BookShop

It could be a little outdated, but I think it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

I usually making PageObjects as Properties for the Steps class and then initializing them in the Steps class Constructor. After that I can do anything with these objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would instantiate the pages as as follows:

```
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace SampleAutomationTests.StepDefinitions
{
[Binding]
public sealed class AuthenticationFeatureSteps
{

    HomePage page = new HomePage(Hooks.Driver);
    AuthenticationPage authpage = new AuthernticationPage(Hooks.Driver);

    [Given(@"I opened the home page")]
    public void GivenIOpenedTheHomePage()
    {
        page.GoTo();
    }

    [Given(@"I navigated to Basic Auth link")]
    public void GivenINavigatedToBasicAuthLink()
    {
        page.GoToAuthenticationPage();
    }
}
}
```